# What format can be easly write in txtFile in java?

Tags: java, json, xml, formatting, gson

I am new in Java. I am so curious to know, which format will be best to write in text file.

For example :

Suppose, I have a data.txt File, where I can save my variables values.

```
food : 100,
play : 20,
money : 50,
sleep : 20,
```

So, Question is : How can i use this text in well Format  ?

I search on Google, found solution xml, json, Gson. Problem is I don't know to  implement this in codeFile.
I would like to use JSON( text become like this or not )

```
{"Values": {
  "food": 100,
  "play": 20,
  "moeny": 300,
  }
}
```

but problems are:

1.) Its external lib - not easy to implement for me.

2.) my code is portable - if i run my code in another PC and there will be also to install json lib for java or not ?

One more Question : Is there already any an other formation in java that can i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by well formatted ? Do you need to send those data to a web service ? a database ?

1. Do you know Maven or Gradle ? they would take care of the dependencies for you.
2. No, once you code is packaged it will come with the dependencies it needs.
3. If the data is that simple "String, Integer" and if the first String is unique I would go for a Map

Edit:

Simple example (read / write) with an HashMap :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MapScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Reading entries
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",(\n)?"));

        final Map<String, Integer> entries = new HashMap<>();
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            final String entry = scanner.next();
            final String[] entrySplited = entry.split(":");

            entries.put(entrySplited[0].trim(), new Integer(entrySplited[1].trim()));
        }

        for(String key : entries.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " : " + entries.get(key));
        }

        scanner.close();

        //Adding a new entry in memory
        entries.put("pizza", new Integer(5));

        //Saving all entries in the data file
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data"))){
            for(String key : entries.keySet()){
                bw.write(key + " : " + entries.get(key) + ",");
                bw.flush();
                bw.newLine();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

It prints :

```
play : 20
sleep : 20
money : 50
food : 100
```

And the file after is equal to :

```
play : 20,
sleep : 20,
pizza : 5,
money : 50,
food : 100,
```

Comment: how do i use Map ? I have only strings and integer in txtFile. Could you give small example of using map ?

Comment: You could simply read from that file and then do some string formatting and place your data into a map. For example use split on the commas to separate your entries and then split on the semicolons to obtain your key and value for your map

Comment: I mean  formatted or easy to read . no i dont need to send that data to web services. No i am not receving file, i am just creating file and save my values in that file.

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt  I search on google Map and found some new searches.. how would be treemap or HashMap ?